# Why does MySql format datetime microseconds as .000000?

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure why, but when a new record is added to my database table, the format of the time is followed by a period and six zeros. An example is

```
2014-03-24 11:00:03.000000
```

I am using the following PHP code get the date and time

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

The record is added to the database via an array, which is passed through the following function:

```
$record = array(
'date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
);
```

Function:

```
$data   = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($record)) . '`';
$values = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $record) . '\'';
mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO `". $table ."` ($data)
    VALUES (". $values .")
");
```

I don't think MySql supports microseconds, so ideally I would like to remove this as it makes my table look messy. Any suggestion on how can I remove the microseconds?

Comment: How do you `INSERT` them? Show us the relevant code.

Comment: `I don't think MySql supports microseconds` You think wrong. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: what is your table column type? you should remove the `fractional seconds part` value from the table definition.There is nothing wrong with your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the format of a `datetime` value when it is returned, then use `date_format()`:

```
select date_format(col, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i;%s') as YYYYMMSS_HHMMSS
```

Don't depend on the database returning a value in a particular format, if you really want it in that format.

As for the question of "why" MySQL does this.  Because it can.  The database is free to return date and datetime values however it likes.  The creators of MySQL chose the most general format for a column that does contain fractional seconds.  The key point is that you shouldn't depend on this, if you want a particular format.  MySQL has excellent functional support for formatting dates and for reading dates from strings.

Comment: The main question remains. *Why does MySql format `datetime` microseconds as `.000000`?*

Answer (score 1):

**Question**:

> *Why does `MySql` format `datetime` microseconds as `.000000`?*

Perhaps at the time of defining the datetime field you might have used precision for microsecond. But while storing data you did not input values for microseconds part.

**What the documentation says**:

*`MySQL 5.6.4`* and up expands fractional seconds support for `TIME`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision.

To define a column that includes a fractional seconds part, use the syntax `type_name(fsp)`, where `type_name` is `TIME`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`, and `fsp` is the fractional seconds precision.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( t TIME(3), dt DATETIME(6) );
```

The `fsp` value, if given, must be in the range `0` to `6`. A value of `0` signifies that there is no fractional part. If omitted, the default precision is `0`. (This differs from the standard SQL default of `6`, for compatibility with previous MySQL versions.)

**Example**:

```
mysql> create table msec( dt datetime, dtfs datetime(6) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)

mysql> insert into msec values ( now(), now() );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> select * from msec;
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| dt                  | dtfs                       |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| 2014-03-24 17:20:44 | 2014-03-24 17:20:44.000000 |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into msec values ( now(), now() + interval 729524 microsecond );
mysql> insert into msec values ( now(), now() + interval 9524 microsecond );

mysql> select * from msec;
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| dt                  | dtfs                       |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| 2014-03-24 17:20:44 | 2014-03-24 17:20:44.000000 |
| 2014-03-24 17:21:22 | 2014-03-24 17:21:22.729524 |
| 2014-03-24 17:22:45 | 2014-03-24 17:22:45.009524 |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the data type of the datetime column to datetime(0):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY datetimecolumnname DATETIME(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the length for date time filed. change some thing like:

> ALTER TABLE `test`.`micro` CHANGE `microsec` `microsec` DATETIME
>   NULL;

Fractional seconds support for `TIME`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` values were introduced in `MySQL5.6.4`

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html